# How to enter workingpaper in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I could need some help figuring out how to properly enter and print working papers with `biblatex-chicago`?

I used to have entries like this (prior to switching to biblatex):

```
@workingpaper{silverstein1981limits-awareness,
    Address = {Austin},
    Author = {Silverstein, Michael},
    Language = {en},
    Number = {84},
    Publisher = {Southwest Educational Development Laboratory},
    Series = {Sociolinguistic Working Paper},
    Title = {The Limits of Awareness},
    Year = {1981}}
```

some also with an url field.

But `biblatex` doesn't include `@workingpaper` anymore. According to the manual one should use the `@unpublished` category. However if I change it to `unpublished` it only prints:

> Silverstein, Michael. 1981. “The Limits of Awareness.” Austin.

which is not enough information if one wants to follow Chicago.  CMoS recommends treating working papers like theses/dissertations or lectures/presentations.  This is the example from their website which I'd like to replicate (adapted for author-date format):

> Dyer, Lee, and Jeff Ericksen. 1980. "Complexity-Based Agile
>   Enterprises: Putting Self-Organizing Emergence to Work." CAHRS Working
>   Paper 08-01, School of Industrial and Labor Relations, Center for
>   Advanced Human Resource Studies, Cornell University, Ithaca, NY.
>   http://digitalcommons.ilr.cornell.edu/cahrswp/473.

Thus for my example above I'd like to end up with (for author date):

> Silverstein, Michael. 1981. "The Limits of Awareness." Sociolinguistic
>   Working Paper 84, Southwest Educational Development Laboratory,
>   Austin.

How do I get `@unpublished` to print that additional information about `publisher`, `series,` and `number`? Or how should I modify my entry to get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `@report` entry type which is described as "A technical report, research report, or white paper published by a university or some other institution. [...] The sponsoring institution goes in the `institution` field." (p. 11 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

The type or series of the report goes into the `type` field (with `biblatex-chicago` `series` would also be acceptable, but the standard styles only allow `type` here, so it seems to be a good idea to stick to `type`), the number of the report into `number`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{silverstein1981limits-awareness,
  author      = {Silverstein, Michael},
  title       = {The Limits of Awareness},
  year        = {1981},
  type        = {Sociolinguistic Working Paper},
  number      = {84},
  institution = {Southwest Educational Development Laboratory},
  address     = {Austin},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{silverstein1981limits-awareness}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Silverstein, Michael. 1981. *The Limits of Awareness.* Sociolinguistic Working Paper 84. Austin: Southwest Educational Development Laboratory.]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I guess that should do.  The only way in which differs from the CMoS website is that it's printed in italics like a book title and CMoS wants it in quotation marks instead.  Any way to change that?

Comment: @jan Technically, yes, it is going to be a bit of a mess though, due to the code structure of `biblatex-chicago`. The author of `biblatex-chicago` notes that he finds the info on `@report`s in the CMS a bit sparse and so went for something similar to `@book`; if you have reasons to doubt that is correct you could give the author a shout so he can re-evaluate things.

Comment: In section "Unpublished and Informally Published Material" under 14.224, it reads: "Titles of unpublished works appear in quotation marks—not in italics."  –––  Do you know if the author is on TEX.SX?  Otherwise I'll write him an email.

Comment: @jan I'm not sure, but he responds to mails quite quickly I believe. You might want to ponder though, if technically we have a work that is really unpublished here. (Normally, I'd argue `@report`s are very much published. You *could* argue it is informally published - but then what does that even mean?)

Comment: Yes, I also think that Chicago's guidelines are a bit odd here.  I would consider a working paper "published" too, if it appears in a series. But they also have thesis/dissertation-titles in quotation marks.

Comment: @jan Mhhh, they don't exactly seem to know what they want. I was wrong about it being complicated though, luckily, `\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}` should be enough.

Comment: I need to come back once more to this thread, is there a way to change the comma after `title` into a dot, as it is with all the other entry types (which is actually how Chicago wants it)?

Comment: @jan `\usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchbibdriver{report}{\newcunit}{\newunit}{}{}`. But that seems to be intentional, maybe you should give the `type` field.

Comment: Hmm, this gives "undefined control sequence" ... printfield{type}\newunit — What should be in the type field? The manual is not very explicit on this.

Comment: @jan That was one of those weird copy and paste things (some invisible char seems to have sneaked into the `\newunit`), try `\usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchbibdriver{report}{\newcunit}{\newunit}{}{}` or copy it manually. The `type` field should hold the type of paper you are referring (whitepaper, ...). I would not mind leaving it out, but because the `biblatex` manual makes it mandatory, so does `biblatex-chicago` (I believe) and so the full stop is turned into a comma.

Comment: Oh, I saw it (it's still there btw, after the u of unit).  But yes, now it works. It also works when Type is specified (then the type field gets the comma), but for a workingpaper I wouldn't need the type.  So this way is better. Thanks a ton for helping out with all that `biblatex` stuff!