# BibLaTeX required fields delimited with a slash

Tags: biblatex

In the BibLaTeX manual (accessible from [the CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)), entry types list required and optional fields. For example,

> article [...]
>
> Required fields: author,title,journaltitle,year/date
>
> [...]

"year" and "date" are distinct fields but delimited by a slash rather than a comma. I expect this means that either year or date can be used. Is this a correct interpretation? This seems evident but I didn't see it explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Is it also acceptable that year *and* date can both be used? Or, is it a strict "OR"? I don't see why you'd want this for year/date, but the slash is also used for author/editor, in which case using both seems more reasonable. If this is the case, the slash seems to mean "at least one of".

Comment: you can use year and date, but then biblatex will use the year from the date field (and issue a warning about this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general "/" in the manual means the classical logical *or* (i.e. at least one). So the

> `author`/`editor`, [...], `doi`/`eprint`/`url`

in the description of `@online` means that you should have an `author` or an `editor` (or both) and at least one of `doi`, `eprint` or `url` (but again, more is obviously fine as well).

**But** things are slightly more tricky with "`date`/`year`". `date` and `year` refer to exactly the piece of information about the work (its date of publication). The `year` field (the same holds for `month`)  is mostly kept for backwards compatibility with BibTeX styles. The preferred way to give the date of publication in `biblatex` is the `date` field. That means that *usually* there is no reason to have both a `year` *and* a  `date` field. In fact the `year` field will be ignored if a `date` is present and a warning will be issued. So you could have both fields at the same time, but I'd recommend against it. Therefore it is better to read the "/" in "`date`/`year`" as an *either ... or*.

Note that from a style perspective it does not matter if you used `year` or `date` in the input, the result is pretty much the same and almost indistinguishable once the data has been read from the `.bib` file.

---

In `biblatex` there is no immediate technical significance of required vs. optional fields apart from Biber's data model verification (`-V`/`--validate-datamodel`). In particular styles don't 'know' which fields are required or optional. Those classifications are at most implicit when style authors implement their style.

§2.3.2 *Missing and Omissible Data*,  p. 34 in v3.16 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says

> The fields marked as ‘required’ in §2.1.1 are not strictly required in
> all cases. The bibliography styles which come with this package can
> get by with as little as a `title` field for most entry types. A book
> published anonymously, a periodical without an explicit editor, or a
> software manual without an explicit author should pose no problem as
> far as the bibliography is concerned. Citation styles, however, may have
> different requirements. For example, an author-year citation scheme
> obviously requires an `author`/`editor` and a `year` field.

So I can only recommend to everyone not to get too hung up on whether or not a field is only optional or required. Make sure your entries contain all available and relevant pieces of information. If a 'required' field is missing in an entry that might be an indication that it would be a good idea double check its appearance in citations and the bibliography to see if you are happy with the output, but that's about it. See also [How to cite report-like documents that do not have/need an institution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/563609/35864).